# Activate SMACK support on Ubuntu

Tags: linux-kernel, security

I'm new with kernel modules and security frameworks in Linux: I've studied SMACK labels and I wanted to test them on my Ubuntu machine.
I wasn't able to use them because in my Linux 4.16.16 kernel configuration:

```
# CONFIG_SECURITY_SMACK is not set
```

How can I add SMACK features to my OS without recompiling the whole kernel?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too hard to recompile the kernel, but if you don't want to do that, your best bet is to find a PPA with another kernel build with that flag set (I didn't find one with a quick search though). After that you should be able to do a bit more setup (see the "Trivial Configuration" section of this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SmackConfiguration

) and change your grub parameters to enable smack during boot. Although note that those docs are becoming dated.

Comment: I haven't found any PPA with that module, moreover I've seen that link but it seems outdated